# Compile time type conversion check (constexpr and user defined literals)

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

**Update: I posted my own answer below** 
And there's a longer version of this matter here: http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/38460349771/c-11-type-safe-use-of-integer-user-defined-literals

**Question:**

I've made a simple `constexpr` user defined literal `_X` that gets the value as an unsigned long long (that's how numeral user defined literals work: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), and then I make sure that the value fits in a signed long long.

It all works well (too big values cause compilation error), but only when I explicitly create a variable such as

```
constexpr auto a= 150_X;
```

If instead I write something typical like

```
cout << 150_X << endl;;
```

the tests are not performed at compile time.

- Are constexpr functions only executed at compile time if they are assigned to a constexpr variable? (I could not find that in the standard)
- Is it possible to achieve the safe behaviour of `_X` that I'm looking for?

Full example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

inline constexpr long long testConv(unsigned long long v) {
  return (v > 100 ) ? throw std::exception() : v; 
} // will eventually use actual limit from numeric_limits

inline constexpr long long operator "" _X(unsigned long long f) { 
  return testConv(f) ;
}

int main(){
  constexpr auto a= 5_X;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << 200_X << std::endl;  // This bad literal is accepted at compile time
  constexpr auto c=250_X;           // This bad literal is not accepted at compile time
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

oh, for reference: I used gcc4.7.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Self answer:***
I found a complete solution, inspired by the comments and other answers to my question, and other questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/13384317/1149664.

The solution is to use the template form of user defined literals and sum up the number manually, multiplying the sum based on the already parsed digits by 10.

I wrote a detailed version of this self-answer here: http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/38460349771/c-11-type-safe-use-of-integer-user-defined-literals

```
template<char... Chars>
int operator"" _steps(){
  return {litparser<0,Chars...>::value};
}
```

Litparser is a little template meta-program which takes a list of characters as arguments expanded from the input characters held by the Chars parameter pack.

```
typedef unsigned long long ULL;

// Delcare the litparser 
template<ULL Sum, char... Chars> struct litparser;

// Specialize on the case where there's at least one character left:
template<ULL Sum, char Head, char... Rest>
struct litparser<Sum, Head, Rest...> {
// parse a digit. recurse with new sum and ramaining digits
  static const ULL value = litparser<
    (Head <'0' || Head >'9') ? throw std::exception() : 
    Sum*10 + Head-'0' , Rest...>::value;
};

// When 'Rest' finally is empty, we reach this terminating case
template<ULL Sum>  struct litparser<Sum> {
  static const ULL value = Sum;
};
```

Comment: Great answer, and thank you for the extended write-up, as well!  Very helpful.

Comment: This, of course, only works as long as the literal is never octal or hexadecimal. In these cases, different literal parser would be required.

Answer (score 3):

`constexpr` functions *may be* executed at compile time; that is, they are *eligible* to be used in constant expressions. If they're not used in a constant expression, there's no point executing them at compile time, although I think it's allowed.

Since you're not allowed to declare a parameter as `constexpr` (section 7.1.5/1) [1], I don't think there is any way to force evaluation of `operator "" _X(unsigned long long)` at compile time, but you can probably do it with `template<char...> operator "" _X()`

If the `constexpr` function is called within a constant expression, the argument will be a constant expression (and if it is not, then the call is not a constant expression). However, you cannot *force* the call to be a constant expression by declaring the *parameter* to be `constexpr`, because you're not allowed to declare parameters as `constexpr`, see reference to standard.

---

[Note 1]: Thanks to @LightnessRacesInOrbit for searching the standard to justify the claim in paragraph two.

Comment: `Since you're not allowed to declare a parameter as constexpr` Hmm, really?

Comment: Hmm yes really (7.1.5/1) - but the `constexpr` requirement is "inherited" from the function being called, when it is being called as part of a constant expression

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it's only "inherited" if the function is called as part of a constant expression. You cannot write the function with a `constexpr` parameter in order to insist that it be part of a constant expression. Was that not clear?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: when I wrote the answer :)

Comment: I don't believe you covered the topic to the extent described in my comments in your answer, though now that I have verified the assertion at the beginning of your second paragraph, the answer makes sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, how's that?

Comment: I thought it was fine as it was but okay :)

Comment: Thank you both for clarifying this. Also, I came up with my own answer based on the template idea.

Answer (score 1):

Constexpr functions need not be executed at compile-time. But your goal can be achieved. For better understanding of the problem, and an example how to create a iteral that is always evaluated at compile-time, I recommend [this post](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/user-defined-literals-part-ii/).

Comment: Thank you, I had already posted my answer when you wrote this. Templates and manual parsing is the way... +1 for you nice blog (which I already follow).